# Why shortcut to a decision is not supported in powerdesigner 15.x UML activity diagrams?

Tags: uml, powerdesigner, activity-diagram

Powerdesigner comes with a nice feature called shortcut to objects. Unfortunately, the shortcuts are not supported for decision objects in UML activity diagrams. Can someone tell me why this is not supported? How can I then use multiple instances of ONE decision object in my activity diagram?

Comment: If you want several symbols for one decision in the same diagram, that would not be a shortcut, but rather a graphical synonym... but it appears that synonyms are not supported either for Decision. It looks like you can only one symbol for a Decision in a diagram; you can still have this single Decision in several diagrams as long as they are under the same model/package...